# node_modules appears empty although i'm in the correct folder - angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i have an angular 4 project which i want to serve via `ng serve`. If i'm doing it inside the command line, inside the project directory (`/hardware/angular-src`) it is no problem.
But when i now try to run `ng serve /hardware/angular-src` from root directory `root@myPc:/$ ng serve /hardware/angular-src` it says `node_modules appears empty you may need to run npm install`

**So this works:**

```
user@myPc:/$ cd /hardware/angular-src
user@myPc:/hardware/angular-src$ ng serve
```

**This works not**

```
user@myPc:/$ ng serve /hardware/angular-src
```

why?

Comment: Well the, run the first command ...

Comment: i need to run `ng serve` from `rc.local` - so i would need to use `cd` inside rc.local before running that script?

Comment: Well if ot works this way, why not. Otherwise, feel free to look at the documentation. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution

use `su pi -c 'cd /hardware/angular-src && ng-serve < /dev/null &'`

that is working like a charme :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, ng serve is meant to run in the **current directory**, in the root folder of a project. You can't invoke it passing it another location as a parameter.

Besides, `ng serve` is meant for development. If you need to run the application in another site, just build it (with `ng build`), copy the `dist` directory and serve the contents of that directory from a web server.

Comment: but it is already working when i run `ng serve` when i "cd"'ed into the folder before. I'll edit my question to make that clear

Comment: Check my modified answer

Comment: much to complicated... i need to develop a frontend for a raspberry pi touchscreen and therefore i need to develop directly on that device

Comment: Then you need to be in the root directory of your project. Is that such an issue?

Comment: i want the pi to directly boot up with nodemon and ng serve running so that i'm able to take the touchscreen / pi combination everywhere and restarting at any time without needing to start nodemon and ng serve by hand